# Excel creates Outlook email but text doesn't align

Tags: excel, vba, email, tabs

I have the attached file which create a receipt to email to the customer.
I'm trying to get the second field to align in the outlook email but have failed to find a solution thus far. Have tried Chr9, vbTab, just adding the spaces etc.
Solutions would be greatly appreciated - I don't imagine its a huge task to fix but it is currently proving elusive.

```
Sub GenerateEmails()

Dim ce As String: ce = "example@email.com"

 'create draft emails
Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup
    If ce Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next

        With OutMail
            .TO = ce
            .CC = ""
            .Subject = "Receipt"
            .Body = "Payment Amount:         " & "$10,000" & vbNewLine & _
                    "Receipt Num:            " & "R645-81658" & vbNewLine & _
                    "Sales Rep:              " & "Ben Smith" & vbNewLine & _
                    "Date Received:          " & "05 July 2016"
            .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried sending in HTML format and using a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Email()

Dim ol As Outlook.Application
Dim olMsg As Outlook.MailItem

Set ol = New Outlook.Application

Set olMsg = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)

olMsg.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
olMsg.HTMLBody = "<TABLE><TR><TD>Cell 1</td><td>Value 1</td></tr>" & _
            "<TR><TD>Cell 2</td><td>Value 2</td></tr>" & _
            "<TR><TD>Cell 3</td><td>Value 3</td></tr></table>"

olMsg.Display

End Sub
```

Also, you could use a font that has the same size per char, like Courier? and use a maxmimum, say 100 spaces, then do a `left("data to be added " & string(100," "),100)`

Comment: @Darren Barson To use this method you will have to activate Microsoft Outlook Object Library in you References if it's not done already.

Comment: Thanks. How do I change the font output to courier? I have zero knowledge of vba in outlook so wondering if there is a way I can do this in the excel output

Comment: I've tried to add a with Font.Name = "Courier" into the mix but no luck

Comment: Completed. I'll just change the outlook font to courier before I run the macro, then change it back afterwards. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I just added the number of spaces needed (I counted how many spaces were needed in the email while I think you made it aligned in your code).

```
    .Body = "Payment Amount:         " & "$10,000" & vbNewLine & _
            "Receipt Num:                " & "R645-81658" & vbNewLine & _
            "Sales Rep:                     " & "Ben Smith" & vbNewLine & _
            "Date Received:             " & "05 July 2016"
```

This is aligned for me. But it is not perfect and it could be by following the advice of @Nathan_Sav and using a table.

Comment: Thanks. I did try this but the text width gave me small spacing issues.